# Android SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an application on Android, which uses database (SQLite). And I want to see tables and values in this database. I use Eclipse and I have ADT installed. So I can easily run my apps on emulator. Anyway, it would be great to have some tool or a program? How can I actually see what is in db files? And how to find them? Thanks.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2149438/tool-to-see-android-database-tables-and-data

Comment: See 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507506/what-are-good-open-source-gui-sqlite-database-managers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is by opening a shell to the emulator and then working with your database through the built in sqlite3 tool.

Example: Assume your app name is "com.example.myapp" and your database name is "mydb"

```
>adb -e shell
>cd data/data/com.example.myapp/databases
>sqlite3 mydb
```

at this point you should have a shell to work with your db.

Some useful commands:

```
.dump
.help
.schema
.exit
```

If you have a table called "my_table", you can use the select syntax to query.

```
select * from my_table;
```

Also, here's a link with more infO: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#sqlite

Answer (score 1):

If you're in the emulator, you can use **adb pull** command at a command prompt and then load the sqlite file in a sqlite viewer.  I've used one that is a Firefox plugin and it worked great.

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#copyfiles

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/

Note that this doesn't work when you deploy to an actual device...

**adb pull** only works with the emulator.  You can get right to the db files on a rooted device as well.

The actualy db file will be a `.sqlite` file at the following location on the emulator:

> data > data > your-package-name > databases > your-database-file.